# Full list / Type of functions that "should be called on each bar for consistency" in Pine Script (TradingView)?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

TradingView provides in the documentation (v5) a [set of functions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html#exceptions) that are exempt from the consistency rule of the execution model, meaning, they don't have to be called on each bar for consistent results.
However, this list seems to be an incomplete draft to me, rather than a full list. I would also expect array functions, like `array.get(id, index) → series` to be mentioned as well, to say the least, if I am thinking correctly.

Would it be safe to say that built-in functions that do not require a *"length"* parameter or are not directly processing data from chart can be safely called from within if conditionals?

My assumptions with examples:

**also safe:**
`math.max(number0, number1, ...) → simple int` (as mentioned in the docs)
`array.from(arg0, arg1, ...) → type[]` (not mentioned)
`str.contains(source, str) → const bool` (not mentioned)

**unsafe:**
`math.sum(source, length) → series float`
`ta.cum(source) → series float`

Actually I think all the `"array"` functions should be listed as well, so do all of `"string", "cast", "box", "color","label","line","linefill","matrix","strategy","table"`, to make the list complete.

Can anyone confirm it or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be safe to say that built-in functions that do not require a
> "length" parameter or are not directly processing data from chart can
> be safely called from within if conditionals?

Yes.

> Actually I think all the "array" functions should be listed as well,

It is better to list functions that should be called in the global scope for consistency.

All `.ta` functions:

```
"ema", "rma", "hma" ,

"sum", "sma", "vwma", "wma", "mom", "cci", "cog", "roc", "dev", 

"percentrank", "variance", "stdev, "supertrend", "falling", "rising", "macd", 

"ta.lowest", "ta.highest", "ta.lowestbars", "ta.highestbars", "atr", "ta.rsi", 

"correlation", "valuewhen", "tsi", "ta.linreg", "stoch", "cum", "swma", "vwap",

 "change", "pivot_point_levels", "barssince", "sar", "cross", "crossover", 

"crossunder", "alma", "cmo", "mfi", "wpr", "dmi", "bb", "bbw", "kc", "kcw", 

"pivothigh", "pivotlow", "percentile_nearest_rank", 

"percentile_linear_interpolation"
```

And a

```
"fixnan", "math.sum"
```